# Convert excel to csv and import data to php

Tags: php, excel, csv, import, converters

I need to import data from excel to php, as I heard It's so hard, so I need convert excel file to csv. But I have the problem, I can't convert successfully, when I trying I get error message: 
[image: errorcsv]

My original excel file looks like:
[image: original]

And after convert to csv:
[image: afterconvert]

What's the problem? I need to convert and keep the same format.

My php file for csv reading looks like:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

And result how It looks like after reading in php: 
[example](http://www.eurokos.lt/zaidimas/test/test.php)

So I need any ideas how to convert xls to csv without loosing format or how to import data from excel file to php. Anyone can help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: why need to convert to CSV? you can directly fetch data from excel to PHP.[Use this](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

Comment: the image at top is not an error message, its a warning. saying your non data items such as formatting, functions will not be saved to the csv file.

Comment: Thank you for answers, but in many topics with similar problems people offering convert to csv, because they said is so hard import data from excel. Maybe they were wrong.
And about warning message thank you for fix, I understood this.

Comment: @Nisarg Patel as you gave me link to PHPExcel I've tried to use this, but unsuccessfully, I don't know how really I can use It. All 3 folders `Classes`, `Documentation` and `Examples` I need to put to my FTP? So how I need to make that It imported data from `test.xls` what I need to change? Thank you.

Comment: The directory called `Classes` contains the actual code; the directory called `Documentation` is documentation about how to use PHPExcel, recommended for you to read, but not essential to run the code; The `Examples` directory isn't essential to run the code either, it contains examples showing how to use PHPExcel - I had thought the three directories were reasonably sensibly named so that their content would be fairly obvious, clearly not

Answer (score 2):

This PHPExcel library have some problems (memory / time ) loading big files. 
If your file is not so big, phpExcel is a good solution, else maybe you have to try loading the data in .csv format directly.

Answer (score 0):

As per your request,

> @Nisarg Patel as you gave me link to PHPExcel I've tried to use this,
>   but unsuccessfully, I don't know how really I can use It. All 3
>   folders Classes, Documentation and Examples I need to put to my FTP?
>   So how I need to make that It imported data from test.xls what I need
>   to change? Thank you.

You can use PHPExcel by this.

Download `Library of PHPExcel` from [HERE](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/downloads/get/688493)

Then include `IOFactory.php` file in your file.

```
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once '../../../includes/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
```

Then Make Object

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("mytest1.xls");
```

After this use `Standard functions of PHPExcel` for fetching data.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I created file: `test.php` which looks like: `<?php
require_once 'IOFactory.php';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("test.xls");
?>` I keep both files test.php and test.xls in the same dir `../Classes/PHPExcel/` but It not import data from test.xls, what mean `Standart functions of PHPExcel'? Thank you again.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the Example files that show how to use PHPExcel? And there's a lot of documentation with the package showing how to read information from Excel files as well

Comment: I misunderstand how to correctly use these examples, I created php file like @Nisarg Patel wrote, but It show blank page. How to use Standart functions I don't understand.

Comment: may be this can help you guys [Check this](http://christoph-burmeister.eu/?p=2036)

Comment: This doesn't work for me too, I did everything like in tutorial, maybe my excel file can't have any format, colors? I need to use format in php as I understood?

Answer (score 0):

> So I need any ideas how to convert xls to csv without loosing format or how to import data from excel file to php. Anyone can help me, please? Thank you.

CSVs don't have any styling capabilities. Excel, Google Docs, Libre, etc... will separate them into cells, but the file itself is just as it's named--comma-separated (or possibly delimited by some other character) list of values. Typically with double quotes denoting strings and newlines denoting rows. The only way I can come up with accomplishing what you want is to encode your values in HTML.